# magento 2.2.1, why this check out step skip add ''Address' if we add ''configuration product' in to cart?

Tags: checkout, configurable-product, onepage-checkout, magento-2.2.1

Using magento 2.2.1. I cannot add address if i add configuration product into cart.

- Does it the role of magento ?
- Can i enable the 'shipping step'?

1 'My configuration product'
[image: Configuration Product]

2. 'Checkout step'
   [image: Checkout Step without 'Shipp']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I could guess, your product has **no weight**. So Magento is considering the product virtual and the product will not be shipped.

That is why it is skipping the shipping address step.

Please try to **add weight for associated simple products** and then check.

Shipping address step will be back.

**Note:** A related problem was posted [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14076) on March 13th, 2018.

Comment: Thank Mohit Kumar Arora. it work by follow your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I add the weight to my product (in the image). It will show 'Shipping Address' in check out step for configuration product.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOO9y.png]